# Accessibility: adjusting click drag delay in Ubuntu

Tags: accessibility

I'm working with someone who cannot click the mouse button very cleanly, and thus ends up dragging icons off the launcher.

In Ubuntu, is it possible to:

a) Lock the icons to the launcher
b) Lengthen the delay that's required before a drag event is recognized?

A similar accessibility issue is http://news.softpedia.com/news/windows-only-click-lock-feature-to-be-built-for-ubuntu-16-04-lts-495904.shtml
(for people who can't keep the mouse clicked during dragging).